# Ошибка при загрузке pypi пакета twine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

При попытке загрузить пакет в Pypi

`python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*`

появляется следующая ошибка

`InvalidDistribution: Cannot find file (or expand pattern): 'dist/*'`

Comment: Он не может открыть файлы по маске. Убедитесь, что в папке `dist` что-то есть и что вы запускаете команду из нужной директории. Или укажите абсолютный путь к `dist`.

Comment: `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` делали?